# Error:Cannot find "Static Main" in Unit test of Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, unit-testing

I have created the Slave Simulator Application using Winforms and had to add the Unit Test Project to it.

I have added the Unit Test Project and also added the proper reference of my application.But when I run the test case, I am getting the error as " Program Does not Contain Static Main method suitable for entry point".I have changed Output type to "Windows Application" and there is a Program.cs(which includes main method) in my Application.

following is my Unit test project code I have written

```
public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestCoilUpdateOperation()
        {
            UpdateCoilsToDataStore testObject = new UpdateCoilsToDataStore();
            bool actualStatus = testObject.UpdateCoils(UpdateCoilsToDataStore.TagName, UpdateCoilsToDataStore.ParameterNames, UpdateCoilsToDataStore.FunctionCode);
            bool expectedStatus = true;
            Assert.AreEqual(expectedStatus, actualStatus);
        }
    }
```

Can you please help me to resolve this problem.
Thanks.

Comment: A unit test project isnt typically executable.  It's a library, and you run the tests using a test runner, such as one built into VS.

Comment: *"I have changed Output type to "Windows Application"* - big mistake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not run the unit test project, it is class library project we can run test by test using Text Explorer instead of running whole project

Add Unit test project, from Test template

[image]

After creating unit test project, write your unit test.

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        //Your logic
        Assert.AreEqual(1, 1);
    }
}
```

**Build your project**, do not run it.

Now use your Text explorer to run particular test.

[image]

Comment: Try to debug your test code, because following all steps mentioned in my answer won't give you error which you mentioned in your question. I believe error is from your code not from test project

Comment: Thank you !!, It worked there was some error in my code.Thanks again.